# Change Re-direct URL after WooCommerce registration

Tags: wordpress, redirect, registration

I stayed up late last night trying to figure this out and just couldn't get it right. Looking for some help, thanks!

Website: http://www.localjoeservices.com

1. Trying to redirect users to a specific URL after they register/login via clicking the "+ Create Your Profile/Login" in the top right menu.
2. WooCommerce defaults to /my-account/ so I did some research and found a plugin called Peter's Login Redirect but I can't seem to get it functioning properly.
3. Running on the Listify Wordpress Theme with WP Job Manager & WooCommerce.
4. Default user role is set to ***customer***

-------- **What I have tried so far** -----------

a) Adding this to functions.php

```html
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');
 
function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
     $redirect_to = 'http://localjoeservices.com/add-my-listing';
     return $redirect_to;
}
```

b) also tried using Peter's Login Redirect plugin with the following settings:

[Peter's Login Redirect - settings screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1nDl.jpg)

c) tried adding this using Code Snippets plugin:

```html
// After registration, redirect to home page
function custom_registration_redirect() {
return home_url(‘/add-your-listing’);
}
add_filter(‘woocommerce_registration_redirect’, ‘custom_registration_redirect’, 20);
```

---

I was inspecting the code on the ajax login popup and saw this code attached to the ***Register*** button:

```html
<p class="woocomerce-FormRow form-row">

<input type="hidden" value="14b8334ba1" name="woocommerce-register-nonce" id="woocommerce-register-nonce"><input type="hidden" value="/my-account/" name="_wp_http_referer">

<input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="woocommerce-Button button">
</p>
```

it shows `value="/my-account/"`, could that possibly be the problem the other methods aren't working?

Really appreciate the feedback!